# Upload file with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, curl, afnetworking

My backend coder provided me with curl example of file uploading:

curl -v -F dictation_file=@file.name -F category=1 http://my.server.com/files/create/

I'm using AFNetworking and the following code is not working:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [parameters setObject:category forKey:@"category"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                                   path:@"files/create/" 
                                                             parameters:parameters 
                                              constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                                  NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:record.filePath];
                                                  [formData appendPartWithFileData:data mimeType:@"application/octet-stream" name:@"dictation_file"];
                                              }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFHTTPRequestOperation operationWithRequest:request 
                                                                          completion:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
    { // handlecodehere
}];
```

However in response json i receive information that dictation_file field is empty. May be i don't understand curl? 
@file.name simply substitude encoded data in field, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify appendPartWithFileData:mimeType:name: method.

On this line

```
[mutableHeaders setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"", name, fileName] forKey:@"Content-Disposition"];
```

instead of **file** i wrote form-data.

Comment: If the server wasn't expecting a file, you should use `-appendPartWithFormData:name:`. No need to change the implementation.